# CI/CD with Craft

Tags: deployment

Does anybody have experience with CI/CD and Craft?

I am testing deploying to PlatformSH but cannot find anything on Google about CI with Craft.

Has anybody setup Travis or something similar on their projects?

Answer (score 2):

We're using GitLab for our CI/CD, but it looks like Travis is really similar in that you'll need to set up a `yaml` file to get things going.

https://blog.travis-ci.com/2019-05-30-setting-up-a-ci-cd-process-on-github

Comment: Thanks Greg. I am planning to use Travis but I don't know where to start with Craft. What processes are you using travis for? I will setup linting for now but I want to create something more complex

Comment: FWIW, you can see Craft's travis.yml file here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/.travis.yml